# Error 404 : While using flag

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

Recently on Stack Overflow I got privilege to flag a post. So when I try to flag a post as duplicate. The diaglog box is not properly loading.

> [image]

However I am easily able to use other flag option like "other","spam" or "offensive".

"other"

> [image]

"spam"

> [image]

"offensive"

> [image]

I am using Google Chrome Version 28.0.1500.71 and Win XP Operating System. I have tried in firefox as well but it is showing me same problem.

Comment: Does the error appear at the same time as the dialog or when you select one of the reasons?

Comment: same time as the dialog

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce. Are you able to get to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/flags/posts/17594909/popup?_=1373550861085)?

Comment: @GeorgeCummins Yes, I am able to see first page of flag dialog. But when I try to select second option, it shows me `404` error.

Comment: Are you able to try in another browser or from another computer, preferably on another network?

Comment: I just tried in Firefox and it is showing same problem :(

Comment: In the absence of any other such reports, you should conduct additional tests to determine whether the problem exists on your end (the computer or the network). Isolating the problem will put you in a good position to fix it.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins, I am able to do flag ( duplicate flag )on meta site, just a minute ago , I used my first flag on meta. But still on S.O. I am not able to flag.

Comment: Now I am able to flag duplicate as well. Has anything changed ?