# Can't flag a question for being off-topic

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags

Just earlier when I was trying to flag a question which I believed to be off-topic, I could not choose that option. A little red box just popped up and said "404".

So I had to just flag it for other and explain that it was off-topic

Comment: It could be a temporary connection problem. Is it working now?

Comment: Which question were you trying to flag?

Comment: dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188400?